# Using MINGW in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

First I have to tell that I have no knowledge of compilers, MINGW etc. at all. Still, I'd like to do the following:

1. Grab a code from somewhere.
2. Feed it to VS 2019.
3. Make VS to build the solution using MINGW-64. I need this because when trying to build the solution I received error messages like this: 'error C3861: '__builtin_clzll': identifier not found' and I have learned that these were because such identifiers were outside of VS and part of MINGW.

I have VS 2019 and MINGW-64 installed. My problem is that I don't know how to make VS recognize and use MINGW.

Your help would be much appreciated.